# Logging .net core 2 write in same console from two project

Tags: logging, asp.net-core

I need to write in the same console from two or more project and so I rolling all content from the console in a text file. Is it possible?

I need this because I would like to know what happened concurrently in more project.

what is the best approach to managing the log in a business context?

I use .net core 2 with logging built-in

Is it possible use another tool for to do this? Some Extention.
What is the

BR

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear. This has little to do with how many projects are at play and more to do with what kind of projects those are. In particular console applications (of which ASP.NET Core projects are) cannot write to the same console because each runs in their own console window. That's fairly logical and understandable.

However, if you're talking about class library projects and such, those can easily output to the same console window as the console app that's referencing them. In fact, that just happens naturally. If you pass in a console logger, the library methods will end up logging to whatever is the active console.

As a result, depending on the project types, what you're talking about either happens naturally or is totally impossible. Given that you're here asking this question in the first place, I have to assume you're talking about multiple console projects; in which case, what you want is not possible. Plain and simple.

However, if your ultimate goal is to dump to a text file, then utilize a logger that actually writes to the text file. Theoretically, if you feed each project's logger the same text file, you can merge all the output together. Logistically, you may have concurrency issues to deal with as well as file locks, so I can't say for sure that that approach will just work. For the best chance, I'd recommend using an actual logging solution that supports writing to a text file, rather than trying to roll your own text file logger. Regardless, that's your best and pretty much only option.